# How do i obtain the conversation history folder from office365?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I am using EWS and wish to obtain the conversation history folder from Office365 Exchange Online.

It was possible to achieve it by the method of judging the folder with DisplayName by the acquisition of the child folder from the root folder.

However, the user can change the name to this folder.

Is there a method that judges from ExtendedProperty to solve this problem?
Moreover, is there an another way?

-code sample-

```
        Folder folder = Folder.Bind(this._exchange, WellKnownFolderName.Root);
        //acquire the total number of cases including the subfolder. 
        FolderView view = new FolderView(1);
        view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        FindFoldersResults result = folder.FindFolders(view);
        //acquire All folders. 
        view.PageSize = result.TotalCount;
        result = folder.FindFolders(view);
        FindFoldersResults folders = folder.FindFolders(view);

        foreach (var f in folders.Folders)
        {
            //I want to judge the history folder of the conversation here excluding the DisplayName property. 
        }
```

Please anyone provide a good idea ,samples.
regards.

Comment: what do you means by "judge"? you want to find specific folder or folders that contain items involved in conversation or what exactly?

Comment: hi, my english translation was wrong. What I want to know is how to get specific folder of conversation history. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if folder contains items from some conversation you can use something like that:

```
var filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.ConversationId, convId);
var itemView = new ItemView();
foreach (var f in folders.Folders)
{
    var findResult = f.FindItems(filter, itemView);
}
```

Filter should restrict find results only to items that has property `ConversationId` equal to conversation you are interested in.

Comment: hi, I am looking for the method to retrieve specific folder as WellKnownFolderName. Is there a way to identificate the OWA default conversation history folder from the property of the folder object? regards.

Comment: I don't think that folder has any property indicating that it is conversation history folder, at least I don't see any of such property. and what do you mean "retrieve specific folder as WellKnownFolderName"? WellKnownFolderName is simply an enum that makes easier binding to standard mailbox folders, it is not something you can get from a folder. and I don't see any value of that enum to be somehow related to conversation history.

Comment: At last, I understood your opinion. Thank you for very useful advice.